# Blazor Server page not rendering when route parameter changes

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a .razor page defined with the following directives:

```
@page "/Search"
@page "/Search/{SearchTerm}"
@page "/Search/{SearchTerm}/{QueryId}"
```

I access the page using these links:

```
<a href="/Search/Page1">Page1</a>
<a href="/Search/Page2">Page2</a>
```

When I load the page the first time, I select Page1.  The page renders successful.  The server code executes.

Using the same tab as the original page, I click Page2 and nothing happens.  The new page does not execute.  The URL does change to the new address.

Thoughts on why the Page2 page does not render properly?  Is something to do with SignalR and routing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Router only sees one Route `/Search` with 2 parameters `SearchTerm` and `QueryId`, so if you want logic to run when those parameters change within the `/Search` route, you'll need to set it `OnParametersSet` or `OnParametersSetAsync`.

Example using the same links as your example above:

```
@page "/Search"
@page "/Search/{SearchTerm}"
@page "/Search/{SearchTerm}/{QueryId}"

<h1>@SearchTerm</h1>
<h2>@_searchTermOnParamChanged</h2>
<h2>OnInitializedAsync @_searchTermOnInit</h2>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? SearchTerm { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string? QueryId { get; set; }
    private string _searchTermOnParamChanged = "";
    private string _searchTermOnInit = "";
   
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _searchTermOnInit = $"SearchTerm just changed to {SearchTerm}";
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        _searchTermOnParamChanged = $"SearchTerm just changed to {SearchTerm}";
        return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In an SPA, navigation is a bit of a misnomer for what is going on: "pseudo-navigation" is closer.

When the SPA starts, the router scans the running assembly and finds all the routes (@Page) defined in objects in the assembly.  These are compiled into a dictionary of route/component relationships.

The router reads the Url on a "Navigation" event, and tries to find the route for the Url in it's dictionary.  If it finds a match it passes the component type, along with any parameters, to the Layout page.  This renders the component.  If the component is the same as that already loaded, only `OnParametersSet{Async}` is run because only the Parameters have changed.

Here's a page to demo what's going on, with a log of what's getting called.

```cs
@page "/"
@page "/Search"
@page "/Search/{SearchTerm}"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@using System.Text;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="m-2 mb-3">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Search/Me">Search for Me</a>
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/Search/You">Search for You</a>
</div>

<pre class="m-2 p-3 bg-dark text-white">
    @this.messages.ToString()
</pre>

@code {
    public StringBuilder messages = new();
    [Parameter] public string? SearchTerm { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.messages.AppendLine($"OnInitialized ran at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} on Url {this.NavManager.Uri}");

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
        => this.messages.AppendLine($"OnParametersSet ran at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} on Url {this.NavManager.Uri}");
}
```

[image]

Comment: This behaviour is maddening. In a restful application, two URLs like mysection/id1 and mysection/id2 are two different resources, yet Blazor is looking at mysection/{id} as one and the same.

Is there a simple way to configure a Blazor Server all to just treat each URL as distinct? Or, if I have to do something in OnParametersSet, is there an easy way to just trigger a refresh?

Comment: @GregMay -  This is a somewhat different question.  Please ask it as a separate question.  This answer is a little stale in the context of Net8!   I'm still active so will provide an answer for you.